# What does the SMS Sends object in the MC Connector do?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect

I have Marketing Cloud connector setup in our Service Cloud org. I have sent SMS messages via Journeys and using Data Extension lists in MC but have noticed none of my accounts show any records in the **SMS Sends** related list.

Can anyone explain the purpose of this list and how/when this is populated?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, this was part of a beta program from sometime in 2016(?). There was documentation about it out there, potential in the release notes, but I just did a quick search and that looks to have been purged.

The system does still keep the related lists, creates workflows relating to SMS, and some accounts have it listed as a send option in their Marketing Cloud Configuration settings, but last I heard it's effectively dead in the water.

Comment: Ditto that comment